Deserialize required property with a getter
I have a class ClassWithRequired with a required property LinkId. That property has a getter that returns the value of another property. When I try to deserialize the class using System.Text.Json, I get a System.Text.Json.JsonException saying that the required property doesn't have a value. The json string contains the underlying property, but not the required property: {"LinkedObject":{"Id":123,"Name":"test"}}
How do I deserialize this class without getting an error?
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonString = "{\"LinkedObject\":{\"Id\":123,\"Name\":\"test\"}}";
            var jsonObj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DerivedClassWithRequired>(jsonString);
        }
    }
    public abstract class BaseClassWithRequired
    {
        public required abstract int LinkId { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedClassWithRequired : BaseClassWithRequired
    {
        public required Link LinkedObject { get; set; }
        public required override int LinkId { get => LinkedObject.Id; set => _ = value; }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        public required int Id { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
    }

}



please provide a [mcve] of your deserialization code

Why is LinkId required and why does it have a (dysfunctional) setter?

Why make it "required" at all, given that the other property it refers to is required? That looks really confusing. I'd just make it [JsonIgnore] public int LinkId => LinkedObject.Id

I've updated my question with a more complete example. This uses a base class, but that shouldn't affect the deserialization at all. The property is required due to business logic, but if it's not possible to deserialize in this manner, I think the required logic can be performed elsewhere.

@EnemySkill: I understand the property is required for business logic, but is the setter on that property required by business logic?

"The property is required due to business logic" - but it will always be present if LinkedObject is present. It seems odd to say "You must set this property when creating an instance, even though we're going to throw away the value" (and that's what required means in C#).

The only purpose of the required property is to ensure that property is set before the object is used. In your case, it's clear that you want the LinkedObject property to be set when this object is constructed, but not the LinkId property. I'm guessing LinkId is a convenience property to help you avoid repetitive property chaining when you're getting that value. So you'll want to change your class to look like this:
public class ClassWithRequired : BaseClassWithRequired
{
    public required Link LinkedObject { get; set; }
    public int LinkId { get => LinkedObject.Id; }
}

Of course, that puts you at odds with the requirements of BaseClassWithRequired. There are two likely reasons for this:
Option 1
Maybe your business logic never actually calls the setter for LinkId. You want the safety of knowing LinkId will have a true value when you go to read it, and you're trying to enforce that by using required ... set;, but in reality you don't want to enforce that this property is set upon construction. As long as your derived class uses required on LinkedObject and Link.Id to ensure LinkId is there when you need it, your domain logic would be just fine if you remove it from the base class:
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract int LinkId { get; }
}

Option 2
Maybe your business logic does actually set the LinkId property on the base class (for example with a constrained generic type), or at least you really do want to enforce that LinkId gets set on when constructing objects inheriting this class. If that's the case, I'm seeing a few problems:

Your child class does not respect the behavioral expectations of the parent class (i.e., calling the setter does not actually change LinkId's value).
You are attempting to construct the child class (via deserialization) without setting the LinkId property.

This leads me to think there's a Separation of Concerns problem. Consider using one class for deserialization, and then transforming from that into a different concrete implementation of the base class at the point where the base class is required.
public class DtoClass
{
    public required Link LinkedObject { get; set; }
}

    var apiInput = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DtoClass>(inputString);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received data for {apiInput.LinkedObject.Name}");
    var domainModel = new DerivedClassWithRequired{
        LinkId = apiInput.LinkedObject.Id // compiler requires setting this property
    };
    businessLogic.ValidateModel(domainModel);


Yeah, this makes sense. I think I will go with Option 2 here. I think I was just trying to have one class be too many things. Thanks!
